# Flask response not returned to AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am using Flask and ajax to connect between my Javascript and Python Script. The objective is: Once a button is clicked in the JSP, the Python script should be triggered. With the code I have shared, I am able to trigger the Python program upon button click. But the response is not getting sent back to the ajax. I have tried various options but still I am not able to get it through.

This is my script.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/crawler",
    data: {testUrl:testUrl},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
        alert(JSON.stringify(response))
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert("failure")
    }
 });
```

This is my python program

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from selenium import webdriver 
from q_learn import Q
from configparser import ConfigParser

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/crawler', methods = ['POST'])
def new():
    url = request.form['testUrl']
    print('url is: ',url)
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read('...Crawler\\config_prop\\config.ini')
    path = parser.get('driver', 'executable_path')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
    URL = url
    q = Q(driver, URL)
    obj = q.QLearn(0.8, 0.8, 0.01, 0.3, 5, 15)
    print(obj)
    driver.close()
    return jsonify(obj)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: This should actually work. Have you tried just returning a simple String or something to see if the connection works and you don't have any errors in your Python processing?

Comment: I had even tried returning simple String but still the issue is the same. I don't find any error in the Python Script hindering the issue and not any in the browser console as well. In fact I just included `alert('Completed!')` inside the javascript after the ajax call. What i believed is that the `alert('Completed')` should be called once the ajax call is completed with corresponding success or failure message that has been acted upon. But instead what i get is upon button click the flask gets triggered and soon after it is triggered it shows the alert message. (1/2)

Comment: And that too, the alert gets popped up just after the triggered program is started. I think it is getting out of the ajax call soon after the flask request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
script:

```
  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/crawler",
                    data: {testUrl: testUrl},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.objt)
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response.objt))
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("failure")
                    }
                });
```

flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from selenium import webdriver
from q_learn import Q
from configparser import ConfigParser

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/crawler', methods = ['POST'])
def crawler():
    url = request.form.get('testUrl')
    print('url is: ',url)
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read('...Crawler\\config_prop\\config.ini')
    path = parser.get('driver', 'executable_path')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
    URL = url
    q = Q(driver, URL)
    obj = q.QLearn(0.8, 0.8, 0.01, 0.3, 5, 15)
    print(obj)
    driver.close()
    return jsonify(objt=obj)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks Emre. I tried this but still no luck! Same issue

Comment: How and where  do you trigger the ajax call? can you send the missing codes if any where do you get that  `q_learn` library, Is it yours, can you include that too?

Comment: I'm sorry as I cannot share the q_learn part of the code. Basically, it is a web crawler and scraper and it takes long to complete. So, when it calls QLearn another chrome browser opens up and navigates to the website and do remaining crawling and reqd scraping as any crawler-scraper do. And, once the crawling-scraping is done, the new chrome window is closed and the scraped data (output) is supposed to be sent back as response to the ajax.

Comment: at least send us the return value of `q.QLearn(0.8, 0.8, 0.01, 0.3, 5, 15)` or is it a secret too?

Comment: The return value of q.QLearn is basically a string like `best path [1, 5, 6, 7, 8] with score 12.0`. This is the minimum possible length of the string. It can also be like 10-15 lines longer. But it is still returned as string (with newline characters if it is more than a line).

Comment: Hi Emre, thanks anyway. In fact the issue was something else on my side. I had refreshed the page each time after the request is sent to flask. So the page before request to flask and the page at the time of response from flask was the issue. I got it right when i played around with the refresh and the request/response.